# Should you receite the Sural Al fatiha during prayer behind Imam?

Tags: salat, jumuah

I know that Sural Al Fatiha is obligatory for any salat prayer my doubt is should you recite the Surah al fatiha silently when you are praying behind the Imam during any kind of prayer like Jamat or Jummuah ?

Or should you just listen to the faitha silently ?

If you don't recite will your prayer be invalid ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just recite it quietly:

Narrated 'Ubada bin As-Samit:
Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Whoever does not recite Al-Fatiha in his prayer, his prayer is invalid."
-Sahih al-Bukhari 756

Comment: It doesn't say the context, it is mandatory for every prayer but when an Imam is praying is it valid in such context is the question